# How do I save a UIButton being selected (showing checkmark) and load it in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am a beginner and the following is what code I have so far. When clicking the button, it'll switch between the checkmark and the empty box (that's good). However, when exiting the app, the button won't save the state of being selected (check marked).

Attached is all my code, so that you can clearly see what's going on.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var checkMarkButton: UIButton!

    let save = "save"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "save") == true {
            checkMarkButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName:                                                   "greyChecked"), for: .normal)

        }else{

            checkMarkButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName:  "greyUnchecked"), for: .normal)

        }
     }




    @IBAction func checkMarkAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
          UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "save")
    }


}
```

[video of what is happening](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AuYbp7hRxyAxkB1nqHQ5QafRGJUf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the image name directly ,I tested my answer it is working

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "checkBoxSave01") == true {
            checkBoxButton1.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "id"), for: .normal)

        }else{
            checkBoxButton1.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "phone"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
    var isFirstClick = true
    @IBAction func checkBoxTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if isFirstClick{
            checkBoxButton1.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "id"), for: .normal)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "checkBoxSave01")
            ifFirstClick = false
        }else{
            checkBoxButton1.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "phone"), for: .normal)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "checkBoxSave01")
            isFirstClick = true
        }

    }
```

Once you click on button `checkBoxSave01`key value will be true until you delete the app.

Comment: I have updated the code above. I decided to make a whole new Xcode project and use the same images. However, it still isn't saving for me and if you follow the link up above, you can see what I'm seeing when I run it.

Comment: @lanSp do you want to change button image in every button actions.

Comment: Yes, like a checklist. I want to be able to check and uncheck and save which ever one is chosen.

Comment: In button action you are saving checkBoxSave01 key value true, but you are not setting image to button.

Comment: Ohhh, I get it. Thank you, it is much appreciated